# Homestead did't generate the second config file in vm nginx

Tags: laravel, homestead

**It seems that my homestead vagrant only generate one site,can't not generate multisite**

**my Homestead.yaml is:**

…

keys:

```
- ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

folders:

```
- map: ~/Code
  to: /home/vagrant/Code
```

sites:

```
- map: homestead.treeline-lumen
  to: /home/vagrant/Code/treeline-lumen/public/
```

sites:

```
- map: homestead.Laravel-5-Bootstrap-3-Starter-Site
  to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel-5-Bootstrap-3-Starter-Site/public/
```

databases:

```
- homestead
```

…

**My homestead version is:**

➜  ~ homestead --version
Laravel Homestead version 2.2.1

**when i ssh into vm ls only one config:**

vagrant@homestead:~$ ls /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/

homestead.Laravel-5-Bootstrap-3-Starter-Site

**and i have**

➜  Homestead git:(master) vagrant destroy

➜  Homestead git:(master) vagrant up

**after changed Homestead.yaml config**

the http://homestead.treeline-lumen:8000/ and http://homestead.laravel-5-bootstrap-3-starter-site:8000/ point to the same project.I want the http://homestead.treeline-lumen:8000/ point the right project.It seems that is the Homestead did't generate the second config file in vm nginx.

How can i resolve this,anybody can help me?

Answer (score 2):

sites:

```
- map: homestead.treeline-lumen
  to: /home/vagrant/Code/treeline-lumen/public/
```

sites:

```
- map: homestead.Laravel-5-Bootstrap-3-Starter-Site
  to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel-5-Bootstrap-3-Starter-Site/public/
```

should be

```
sites:

    - map: homestead.treeline-lumen
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/treeline-lumen/public/

    - map: homestead.Laravel-5-Bootstrap-3-Starter-Site
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel-5-Bootstrap-3-Starter-Site/public/
```

And to reprovision without having to destroy it can be done with

```
vagrant up --provision
```

Comment: Thanks you very much.